# How can I get better tick spacing for multiple ListLogPlots?

Tags: plotting

I am using `Show` with `PlotRange -> All` to overplot multiple `ListLogLogPlot`.
The resulting plot has axis ticks that are unevenly clustered toward the top of the y-axis. (right image)

When I use `Show` with `PlotRange -> All` to overplot the same data using `ListPlot`, the resulting plot has evenly spaced ticks along the y-axis (left image).

[image]

How can I use `Show` with `PlotRange -> All` to overplot `ListLogLogPlot` and get even axis ticks along the y-axis? I can force a fix by specifying the entire range with `PlotRange` in the first plot, but in general I will not know ahead of time the plot ranges and would like to avoid editing the plots themselves.

Comment: Could you post the code for a small working example?

Comment: Because for example this `y[x_, p_] := Log[x]/p - p/2;
a[p_] := Table[{x, y[x, p]}, {x, 10^3, 10^4, 10}];
ListLogLogPlot[{a[3.7], a[3], a[2]}, PlotRange -> All]` plots without problem.

Comment: This problem arises because the `Ticks` specification from the first plot--obviously the red one in this case--covers only a narrow range and carries through to the output. Ideally, one should re-generate the ticks over the complete range of the combined plot.

Answer (score 3):

`Show` takes the options from the first graphics object in its input. This means that when you have two graphs, one with `Ticks` specified and one without and you put the one with `Ticks` first, this will dictate the `Ticks` in the overall output. If you put them second then the `Ticks->Automatic` option from the first graph will be used. You can however override this by specifying `Ticks->Automatic` in the `Show` command itself. Let's say we have two plots defined by:

```
p1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, Ticks -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}}];
p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}];
```

We can get three very different results, depending on the ordering in `Show` and the options we give `Show`:

```
pa = Show[p1, p2];
pb = Show[p2, p1];
pc = Show[p1, p2, Ticks -> Automatic];
```

[image: three different versions]

In the first plot the first element of `Show` has `Ticks` specified and thus this is the option used. You can also see that the `PlotRange` is taken from the first plot.

In the second plot, the first element is `p2` and this has the `Ticks` option as the default value. This is then used for the overall graphics object.

In the third plot, while the first element is `p1`, we can override the option by specifying `Ticks` in the `Show` command. Note however that the `PlotRange` is still that from the first plot and not from the second.

All of this and more can be found in the details part of the documentation for `Show`.